# tensorflow slice after pad doesnt work while without pad it does

Tags: python, tensorflow

using tensorflow 1.8

I have a RNN where I am trying to pad and then slice the features to  normalized sentences of variable length

```
# param.batch_size = 32 params.max_doc_len = 10
# features is of shape [32, 800+]
features = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(features, default_value=0)
features = tf.Print(features, [tf.shape(features), features], "Features after sparse2dense")

features = tf.pad(features, tf.constant([[0, 0], [0, params.max_doc_len]]), "CONSTANT")
features = tf.Print(features, [tf.shape(features), features], "Features after pad")

# same output with 
# features = features[:, :params.max_doc_len]
features = tf.strided_slice(features, [0,0], [params.batch_size, params.max_doc_len], [1,1])
features = tf.Print(features, [tf.shape(features), features], "Features after pad and drop")
```

However on slicing I get the wrong dimensions:

```
Features after sparse2dense[32 858][[1038 5 104]...]
Features after pad[32 868][[1038 5 104]...]
Features after pad and drop[10 10][[1038 5 104]...]
```

If I remove the pad operation I get the correct output as below:

```
Features after sparse2dense[32 858][[1038 5 104]...]
Features after pad and drop[32 10][[1038 5 104]...]
```

The worst part is that the same code works fine in a notebook (versions match)

```
t = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4,3,2],[1, 2, 3], [4,3,2],[1, 2, 3],[9, 9, 9]])
MAX_DOC_LEN = 5
paddings = tf.constant([[0, 0], [0, MAX_DOC_LEN]])

padded = tf.pad(t, paddings, "CONSTANT")
cropped = padded[:, :MAX_DOC_LEN]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(tf.shape(t).eval()) # [6 3]
    print(tf.shape(padded).eval()) # [6 8]
    print(tf.shape(cropped).eval()) # [6 5]
```

**Now the question is what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171685/discussion-on-question-by-codebreach-tensorflow-slice-after-pad-doesnt-work-whil).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to right-pad each row with zeros so that the length becomes fixed. Turns out there is a really simple solution to that, right in the first line of your code (note I've replaced [`tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_tensor_to_dense) to [`tf.sparse_to_dense()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_to_dense) - these are different!):

```py
filter = tf.less( features.indices[ :, 1 ], params.max_doc_len )
features = tf.sparse_retain( features, filter )
features = tf.sparse_to_dense( sparse_indices = features.indices,
                               output_shape   = ( params.batch_size, params.max_doc_len ),
                               sparse_values  = features.values, 
                               default_value  = 0 )
```

The first two lines just implement a filter to throw away any values that would be beyond the `max_doc_len`, so basically truncating all rows.

The main idea here is that [`tf.sparse_to_dense()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_to_dense) allows manual specification of the resulting tensor's shape, which we want here, and it fills the rest with zeroes anyway. So this one line does what your section of code is for.

P.S. Notwithstanding, the probable bug in TensorFlow remains, but I was unable to reproduce the issue anywhere.

Comment: somehow this also doesn't work. Following is the error: `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[10] = [0,10] is out of bounds: need 0 <= index < [32,10]
         [[Node: RNN/SparseToDense = SparseToDense[T=DT_INT64, Tindices=DT_INT64, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](DeserializeSparse, RNN/
SparseToDense/output_shape, DeserializeSparse:1, global_step/add/y)]]`

Comment: worth to mention (maybe) that I am using the new dataset API along with an Estimator. I figured it would be best to use the new stuff when starting a new model...

Comment: This looks legit, is the shape is `[ 32, 10 ]` then you can't have an index of `10` ( in `[ 0, 10 ]` ), because it's zero-based, so the index must be between 0 and 9.

Comment: Right....only I this is from the `sparse_to_dense` call you suggested. 
Does that mean that I have to somehow drop indices and values > max_doc_len before I call that function? I am not sure how to do that and that was the reason for all the craziness I had

Comment: First get the `max_index = tf.reduce_max( features.indices )` that will tell you the largest index. Do `length = tf.maximum( max_index, params.max_doc_len )` to set a floor. Use that in the `sparse_to_dense`. Then do the slicing like `[ :, : params.max_doc_len ]`.

Comment: Added two more lines to the code in my answer to throw away values that would be beyond the `max_doc_len`